# When do i use は for きのう,きょう,あした?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, word-usage

Example from Minna No Nihongo:

Lesson 4 : 
**あした** 6 時に起きます。

Lesson 9 :
**きょう** **は**　早く　帰ります。

Why is は sometimes used with such a time words and sometimes not?

Answer (score 1):

- As in many other situations 'は ha/wa' can denote a special
  significance this time. For example あした 6 時に起きます。plainly states that
  the subject of the sentence will wake up at 6 tomorrow.
- For the other
  example, きょう は　早く　帰ります。 there is a 'は ha/wa' inserted so it would add
  a nuance that I am waking up early today AND that this is not common
  for me to do this, i.e. normally I would wake up later.

In spoken English you might accentuate the "Today" as in "TODAY, I'm waking up early."

Answer (score 0):

は:

1. Denotes the topic.
2. For comparing, emphasis

So in your second example

> きょう は　早く　帰ります。

You wanna emphasize **TODAY**, you may always go back home late, but not today.